# One-Way ANOVA for two groups VS. t test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, t-test

When comparing 2 groups (K=2), we can either perform a t-test or f-test of One-Way ANOVA, because the f-test is equal the t-test squared(t^2 = f), it essentially goves the same resilt, right ?
Only with two groups we can have a directional hypothesis (one-tailed), but then if for example, I use in my t-test alpha=0.05, I'll have to use for the ANOVA alpha=0.1.
I'd like to know why is that ?
How's it possible that the power stays the same as t-test ?
How's that the significant level doesn't change ?

Comment: How will you test a directional hypothesis with an ANOVA?

Comment: When you campare between 2 groups the test  is parallel to  t-test. While the f-distribution is not for one tailed hypothesis, however if you only have two groups you're allowed to examine a directional hypothesis

Comment: OK so if you run an ANOVA, get p<0.1, but the effect is in the wrong direction, then you accept H0?  If so then your test procedure has alpha=0.05, since under H0 the distribution of the test statistic is symmetric about 0.

Comment: `if for example, I use in my t-test alpha=0.05, I'll have to use for the ANOVA alpha=0.1` I'm not so sure I agree with this. What is your rationale?

Comment: When you have more than 2 groups, it's not possible to have a directional hypothesis.

Comment: with two groups,the t-statistic ^2 is equal the f statistic.then,when the descriptive statistics are compatible with your hypothesis you can check a directional. in order to get the same conclusion all the time we need to extend our alpha in our f test. Think of it like that- the critical t ^2 (0f 0.025) is equal to the critical f (of 0.05), therefore when you have one tailed hypothesis and use alpha of 0.05 only in one side, the critical t ^2 (of 0.05) will be the critical of f (of 0.1). That is to get the same conclusion.

Comment: No, both tails of the t-test goes into the same (one!) tail of the F-test. The reason is simply that $(-t)^2 = t^2$ !